# Creating survey using software - but have to customize one item

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a questionnaire where I would like to ask for an answer in a text form, however, i do not want to store that answer but instead store it as a number. 
Do you know any software that would allow me to do it, or would I have to code it myself? And if so, could you advise what would be the best way?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you will have to write the code yourself. Yes, the requirement is possible.

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two native browser technologies that allows the conversion of alphabetic characters to numeric characters are `String.prototype.codePointAt()` and `TextEncoder` `.encode()`.

For example

```
const answer = "answer";
const numeric = [...answer].map(char => char.codePointAt(0)); // array
```

or

```
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const numeric = encoder.encode(answer); // typed array
```